# Update issues on local laravel valet

Tags: updating, composer

When I update any plugins ( and I mean any not specific) the vendor package vlucas (Php DotEnv) is removed and the site subsequently breaks complaining it cannot find the DOT env file. Manual update via composer update doesn't work/resolve

It seems the only remedy for this is to manually add from production site the vlucas package and the vendor/composer package

Is there something broken in these packages?

Answer (score 1):

Can you update your `composer.json` to require `"vlucas/phpdotenv": "^3.4.0"` and run `composer update` again.